# How to serve a page with only a title bar and content, nothing else?

Tags: javascript, cgi, onload

I have a web page jammed full with a few hundred rows of tabular numerical data. It's fearsome. The user wants to see as many data rows as he can in one single view, without scrolling vertically. I'm thinking to serve that page with just a title bar -- no back or refresh button, no address bar, no Google toolbar, no status pane, nothing but a title bar. The user reaches the page by way of a normal html link.

Is there a way to do that in the CGI that writes the page? The CGI is already writing content and cache-control headers.

If not, then (next best thing) is there a way to do it with JavaScript, without opening a new browser window, perhaps in the onload event handler?

Thanks!

Comment: In which browser? In which operating system?

Comment: @Rob Raisch -- In any browser; in any operating system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure you can't do this cross browser and I'm positive you can't do it server side. However most browsers allow a full screen view which the user can get to.

In Internet Explorer and firefox the shortcut is F11. I know that's not the solution your looking for. However I'm pretty sure thats all there is.

---

I didn't see n0nick answer when I typed mine up. I agree with his answer I'm leaving mine in here for the F11 part.

Comment: Your solution is *much better* than the one I was looking for: F11 gives exactly the effect I want and I don't have to worry about crippling the user inadvertently. Thanks!

Comment: F11 works in Firefox, Internet Explorer, and Chrome; not Safari. Close enough, by my lights.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to do that in the CGI that writes the page?

No.

> If not, then (next best thing) is there a way to do it with JavaScript, without opening a new browser window, perhaps in the onload event handler?

Well, you could, on `onload` [open a new ("chromeless") browser window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open#section_7) with your page, but that's about it.
You can't control the user's current browser window from within an HTML page.